# 3D Sobel Operator Algorith in C

Tags: c, image-processing, 3d, edge-detection, sobel

I'm currently struggling to make a 3D Sobel edge detector in C (which I am quite new to). It's not exactly working as expected (highlighting non-edges within a solid 3D object) and I was hoping someone might see where I've gone wrong. (and sorry for the poor spacing in this post)

First of all, `im` is the input image which has been copied into `tm` with a 1 pixel border on each side.

I loop through the image:

```
for (z = im.zlo; z <= im.zhi; z++) {
    for (y = im.ylo; y <= im.yhi; y++) {
        for (x = im.xlo; x <= im.xhi; x++) {
```

I make an array which will house the change in the `x`, `y`, and `z` directions, and loop through a 3x3x3 cube:

```
    int dxdydz[3] = {0, 0, 0};
    for (a = -1; a < 2; a++) {
        for (b = -1; b < 2; b++) {
            for (c = -1; c < 2; c++) {
```

Now here's the meat, where it gets a bit tricky. I'm weighting my Sobel operator such that if you imagine one 2D surface of the kernel, it would be {{1,2,1},{2,4,2},{1,2,1}}. In other words, the weight of a kernel pixel is related to its 4-connected nearness to the center pixel.

To accomplish this, I define `e` as 3 - (|a| + |b| + |c|), so that it is either 0, 1, or 2. The kernel will be weighted by 3^e at each pixel.

The sign of the kernel pixel will just be determined by the sign of `a`, `b`, or `c`.

```
                int e = 3 - (abs(a) + abs(b) + abs(c));
```

Now I loop through `a`, `b`, and `c` by packaging them into an array and looping from 0-1-2. When `a` for example is 0, we don't want to add any values to `x`, so we exclude that with an if statement (8 levels deep!).

```
                int abc[3] = {a, b, c};
                for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if (abc[i] != 0) {
```

The value to add should just be the image value at that pixel multiplied by the kernel value at that pixel. `abc[i]` is just -1 or 1, and `(int)pow(3, e)` is the nearness-to-center weight.

```
                        dxdydz[i] += abc[i]*(int)pow(3, e)*tm.u[z+a][y+b][x+c];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Lastly take the sqrt of the sum of the squared changes in `x`, `y`, and `z`.

```
    int mag2 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    mag2 += (int)pow(dxdydz[i], 2);
    }
        im.u[z][y][x] = (int)sqrt(mag2);
    }
}
}
```

Of course I could just loop through the image and multiply 3x3x3 cubes by the 3D kernels:

```
int kx[3][3][3] = {{{-1,-2,-1},{0,0,0},{1,2,1}},
  {{-2,-4,-2},{0,0,0},{2,4,2}},
  {{-1,-2,-1},{0,0,0},{1,2,1}}}; 
int ky[3][3][3] = {{{-1,-2,-1},{-2,-4,-2},{-1,-2,-1}},
      {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}},
      {{1,2,1},{2,4,2},{1,2,1}}}; 
int kz[3][3][3] = {{{-1,0,1},{-2,0,2},{-1,0,1}},
      {{-2,0,2},{-4,0,4},{-2,0,2}},
      {{-1,0,1},{-1,0,1},{-1,0,1}}};
```

But I think the loop approach is a lot sexier.

Comment: Please try to provide your code quotes in a more consisitent way (the term "code puzzle" comes to mind). A [mcve] would be ideal. You can assume that whatever graphic library is used is available, but maybe you can remove the actual graphic part and only work on data to demonstrate the undesired behaviour.

Comment: You probably mean to say `pow(2, e)`, not 3. I would use a lookup table for this, `pow` is quite expensive: `weight[e]`.

Comment: Also, why does your code say `tm.u` in one place but `im.u` in another? You should only post code here that you have compiled and run, paraphrasing your code is not helpful!

Comment: Yes, it's `pow(2, e)`. `tm` doesn't change, `im` gets updated. I think I solved my answer, will update when I get a chance.